# Submit iOS app with different technology

Tags: ios, xcode

I have question about publishing app to Apple AppStore. I have old app written in Xcode (swift). Now I want replace this app with new written in React native. Is possible to change whole code of app?

Comment: You are not changing the code you are changing the binary. Since you have same bundle id, you will "replace" old by new in a transparent way for users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can, as it is just a binary, as long as you are using the same bundle identifier, you can update the app.

**How you can do** -

In iTunes Connect, instead of clicking on 'Add New Application' in 'Manage Your Applications', you have to go the application you are updating and clicking 'Add Version'. After that you can upload your new binary, it will go as an update.